# Selecting a git workflow for my situation

Tags: django, git

I'm new to git.  I've read the [well-written intro book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).  But gee, it's still not a trivial topic. I've been bumbling around, experiencing various problems.  I realized it might be because I'm unaware of workflow, and specifically, "what are the best practices for doing what I'm trying to do?"

I started out developing a django project on my win7 with Pycharm. Great way to get the initial 95% written.

But then I need to deploy it to my production machine at PythonAnywhere.

So I created a private Github repository,  pushed my win7 codebase to github.

Then in pythonAnywhere, I cloned the github repository.

For now, no others work on this project. It will not be released to the public.

Now that the server is running on PythonAnywhere,  I still need to tweak settings, which is best done on the PythonAnywhere codebase side.  But there are other improvements (new pages, or views) that I'd rather do inside Pycharm IDE on my win7 than in vim on python anywhere.

So I've been kind of clumsily pushing and fetching these changes.  It's been kind of ham-handed, and I've managed to lose some minor changes through ignorance.

So I'm wondering if anyone can point to a relatively simple workflow that would handle the various tasks I mentioned:
1) improving functionality of the site (best done in Pycharm IDE)
2) production server issues and tweaks (best done on PythonAnywhere)
3) keeping everythign safely backed-up on Github

The other issue is that I have another django app that I want to build.  It's easiest to temporarily hang it off the django project I've already built.  But I'd prefer to keep it in its own repository.

So I have Original_Project, Original_App  stored in Original_Repository
I want to make new_app, and have it, for the time being, run in Original_Project, but I want to version control it in New_Repository.

I think/hope that I could put a .gitignore in the Original_Repository, saying ignore the new_app/  Then I `git init` `new_app/` as its own repository.  Is that sound or mad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid editing your code on the production server as much as possible, and *never* commit from the production server. If you end up having to tweaks things on the server (you shouldn't but well, shit happens and sometimes it's indeed easier to first get the code back to work on the server), then once it's working manually report your edits to your local repo, clear up the changes on the server and deploy the fixed code again.  Here the github repo should be considered as the "master" repository for deployments, ie you work on your local repo, push to github, and on the server pull from github. This make sure you keep the github repo in sync.

wrt/ the "improving functionality" (aka "features") vs "server issues and tweaks" (aka "hotfixes"), git flow is a (mostly) sane workflow IMHO but that's a bit opinion-based here (some dislike it and have sensible arguments too).

Finally if you want to factor out one of your apps, the best is to have it in it's own (github) repo with all the [proper python packaging stuff](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and make it a [requirement](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) of your main project. On your local dev environment you [install it as an editable package](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs), and for the production setup you install it as normal package pinned to the last stable version. Note that in both cases I assume you're using virtualenvs (and if you dont, well that's the very first issue you should address).

**Update:**

> What are the downsides of of editing directly on the production server and committing from the production server?

Well quite simply a production server is not the place for coding - "production" means that you have users trying to do something with your website and they don't want to have the site breaking on them, their data lost or whatever because you are "tweaking" things. You should only deploy stable, well tested code on production, and the one and only one case where editing anything on the server *might* be a last resort option is when it's already broken and you want to get it back online asap whatever it takes (case of "first make it work, then make it clean").

Point is, I'm a professional developer working on projects that are business criticals and a broken site is not an option, so I'm very strict on this - but even if it's a hobby project, your users deserve some respect (at least if you expect to see them back).

A proper production chain actually involves at least three environments: your local dev environment, a staging server (which should closely mirror the production server - system, system package versions, configurations etc etc) to test out / showcase / eventually do minor config tweak, and the production server which should only ever see stable tested code.

Comment: Thanks for all the color.  What are the downsides of of editing directly on the production server and committing from the production server?

Answer (score 0):

I have always struggled with git, knowing it well enough to get thigs working, but never being sure I am doing thing well.

I would suggest installing [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) (it is probably available in your package manager if you are on Linux). Its a set of extensions that simplify a standard git worklfow. Since using it, this has pretty much been all the documentation I have needed.

https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/